# DomDocument and special characters written in two bytes

Tags: php, xml, dom, character-encoding, domdocument

I have a web application, written in PHP, based on *UTF-8* (both *PHP* and *MySQL* are on *UTF-8*). Everything is beautiful - no problem with special characters.

However, I had to build an export to *XML* with encoding *ISO-8859-2* (Polish), so I picked DomDocument because it has built in encoding conversion.

But when I had sent the *XML* to my partner for validation, he said that one of tags have too many characters. It was strange because it had the specific maximum number of characters. Then I have opened the file in HexEditor and saw that every special character has two bytes.

I have tried to convert the result with iconv and mb_convert_encoding.

Iconv says:

```
iconv() [<a href='function.iconv'>function.iconv</a>]: Detected an illegal character in input string in file application/controllers/report/export.php at 169
```

mb_convert_encoding is simply deleting all special characters and result is encoded in ASCII.

Is there a way to convert the output of DomDocument to one-byte characters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably show more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem when switching between encodings is that, even with transliteration, not all characters are representable in other encodings in a single byte.

For example, consider the [EURO SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm), a character that takes 3 bytes when encoded in UTF-8. If you look at the [charset support page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/charset_support.htm), you can see that ISO-8859-2 is not listed.

Since there is not a single character to represent the euro sign, then transliteration does its best to still represent it in the output

```
echo iconv( 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2//TRANSLIT', '€' ); // EUR
```

In this example, we still end up with 3 bytes to represent the euro sign after transliterating.

### EDIT

**P.S.** The NOTICE level error you're getting is because you executed iconv() *without* the transliteration flag.  And as I highlighted above, the EURO SIGN doesn't exist in ISO-8859-2, so you clearly have at least one character in your data that also doesn't exist in ISO-8859-2, so you'll *have* to use transliteration.  Just know that it doesn't guarantee that you'll get down to 1 byte/char.